# Is *Network operator* considered singular or plural?

Tags: verbs, nouns, grammatical-number

> Network Operator pays Company X, and Company X pays Ringtone Provider
>   Network Operator pay Company X, and Company X pay Ringtone Provider

Which one is correct?

Comment: Voting to close.  This is a question about whether organisations should be treated as singular or plural. Already discussed on this forum many times before (http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collective-nouns+grammatical-number), and you can find good answers in standard reference books on English usage.

Answer (score 0):

The network operator acts as a single entity and is therefore considered in the singular, i.e. "Network Operator pays...".

Comment: References? Why should we believe you?

Comment: References to what, exactly? All of this is obvious.

Comment: Reference to a corpus of the English language? Or a usage guide? Or just link to answers given previously (see the links in the comments to this question.)

Comment: It might be obvious in American English, but in British English, it is just as obviously wrong.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Oh no, don't go and spoil the surprise. I wanted Newb to find that out for himself. But since you've let the cat out of the bag, I'll expand on your answer: In British English, either the singular or plural are fine. In America, some stylists maintain that only the singular is acceptable, but this is a matter for debate. However, in this context, the singular is clearly more appropriate because the organisations are being treated as parties to a financial transaction. So Newb was right, but perhaps not for the right reasons.

Comment: @Pitarou Whether you subscribe to British or American English is almost totally irrelevant: as you said, the context makes it blatantly clear that the singular is the appropriate choice. Moreover, if you had a particular issue with my answer, it would've been more productive to post your concern outright rather than to play coy and ask for references, which is a waste of time for everyone involved. (Keep in mind that core to the mission of SE is providing high-quality, correct answers.)

Comment: @Newb Correct? Yes. High quality? No. "It's obvious" is not very useful to the person asking the question.